# Rename folder alfresco automatically

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have the folder DEPARTMENT created as a folder model in Data Dictionary/Space Template as follows:

- Parent folder: DEPARTMENT
- Child folder: Client_DEPARTMENT

I want when i create a folder based on the Template folder (DEPARTMENT) and rename it (to the proper name department) to automatically rename the child folder.

Example:

HR/Client_HR

How can i do that? How can I apply a script to a folder and not a document?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write your code as a rule using the JavaScript API, and apply that rule to the template folder. When defining this rule, you can choose to apply it only to folders with a bunch of others options.

When you create a folder based on this template, the rule will also be copied along and executed.

https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/library-folder-rules-define-create.html

Comment: But those rules are only executed when there is a document uploaded/modified/deleted from the folder. What I want is execute the script when my FOLDER is created

Comment: You will have a rule active on "department" that will say: When a node child is created, and when that node is of type "folder", change it's name to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this with a folder rule, in general, I'd suggest using a behavior (see http://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/references/dev-extension-points-behaviors.html). You could have a custom folder type for your template and then bind the onCreateNode event for your folder type. Jeff Potts has a good tutorial on this too on his ecmarchitect.com site (go here for the behavior one directly - https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/behaviors/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice advice too, however it would require writing Java code, compiling it, deploying, restarting and so on, the rule option is a more "adhoc" solution.

Comment: I agree in part. If you want something adhoc and you only have a single environment (e.g. production), then go for it. However, if you have a release process that pushes through other environments (qa, staging, etc.) before going to production, you want to make sure that this is easily deployable and perhaps even create unit or integration tests for it. In that case, it's better to package it in a module (possibly with other configs/customizations).